# How to Send JSON from Javascript to BackingBean using JSF and Primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, primefaces, jsf-2

In my project i'm sending the JSON(or data) value from JSF Backbeanmethod  to Javascript using RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam() method. this works perfect for me. now how to do the vice-versa (ie) send the JSON data from Javascript to BackingBean method using JSF and Primefaces.

Comment: just like you would send a normal string from javascript to the bean, but just encode it first. More than one example/question of this on stackoverflow

Comment: @Kukeltje can you please share me an example ? and i dont want to pass a string, i need to pass an object,

Comment: no need to... Read my comment... jason is a plain text string...